# In Vertex Tool (QGIS 3.2.2) How can I select the next (or previous) vertex?

Tags: select, vertices

I want to correct a duplicate vertex by deleting one.

However, if I use click and drag, I select both and delete both.  To select only one, I could select the previous (or next) vertex and navigate to the next (or previous) one and then delete.

I can't find a keyboard shortcut or menu option to navigate-select to next vertex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While editing, -Vertex Tool should be selected- right click on the vertex/edge to open menu and select Vertex Editor to open it. In Vertex Editor select any duplicate vertex. Then, using up/down arrow keys you can select previous/next vertex and can remove that vertex by pressing delete key easily.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to the selected vertex to be highlighted? When you have a single vertex selected it to get blue, but when you have one above another it is not possible to see where it is.

Comment: @christian.gobel I noticed that but I have no idea. Why do you need that? And you can ask new question about this issue.

Comment: Yes, sure. I have a path (tracks) generated by points that at some point overlay each other. When you select in the Vertex Editor the first vertex, and this means a vertex that is below, it does not get highlighted.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318708/how-to-select-and-move-below-vertex-vertex-tool-qgis-3-6