# How to select and move below vertex - Vertex Tool (QGIS 3.6)

Tags: qgis-3, vertices, nodes

I have a path (tracks) generated by points, which I snapped before to a grid (so there is some vertex at the way back that are overlayed), that at some point overlay each other. When you select in the Vertex Editor the first vertex, and this means a vertex that is below, it does not get highlighted.

[image]

When you have a single vertex selected it gets blue, but when you have one above another it is not possible to see where it is, neither move or edit it.

Is there a way to the selected vertex to be highlighted even if it is under another vertex?